# Can I use Cloudflare to 301 redirect domains without A records?

Tags: redirect, dns, cloudflare

I am using CloudFlare to manage my websites DNS. I want to use Page Rules to setup redirects for a number of URLs to go to another website URL.

Currently my hosting account, I have set them all up as addon domains and then setup redirects in CPanel.

I am moving across my sites to my own cloud server without a CPanel - I am using VestaCP. I don't want to clutter up the website records by adding each and every site I want to redirect to the host (there is a dozen of them) - I want Cloudflare to manage it all.

Is it possible to do this? Like use Cloudflare page rules and remove the A record pointing to the host server IP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for you to use Page Rule to redirect to another site, there are 2 conditions:

1. Valid A record or CNAME record
2. That record is orange-clouded

The A record can point to any public IP address, for example 8.8.8.8, it doesn't matter because the visitor will be redirected away anyway. However it can't be IP address that belongs to Cloudflare (e.g. 1.1.1.1). 
Similarly to CNAME record, can be pointed to any domain/subdomain (e.g google.com).

Cloudflare has a [KB article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-Configuring-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-Page-Rules) that explains how you can configure the Page Rule to do the 301 redirection.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will give it a go with the 8.8.8.8.8 IP address and use the Page Rule 301 redirection and see how that works.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks very much. This was the answer I was looking for.